# Turning C program to MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, mips

I have an assignment and I don't understand how to turn C code to assembly.

> Suppose you have an array of 12. Rearrange the contents of the array so they are sorted from smallest to largest (from A[0] to A[12]).**
>
> Address: 12, 8, 4, 0
>
> Data:   1, 6, 4, 2

So the end result should be: A[0]==1, A[4]==2, A[8]==4, A[12]==6

This is my C code:

```
int x, i=12;
while(A[i] < A[i-4])
{
x = A[i];
A[i] = A[i-4];
A[i-4] = x;
i -= 4;
}
```

So now I have to translate that code to mips but I'm stuck. This is what I've made so far:

```
addi $t1, $t1, 12   #$t1 = i
sll $t0, $t1, 2
add $t0, $t0, $s6   #$s6 = A[]

lw $t2, 0($s6)
lw $t3, 4($s6)
lw $t4, 8($s6)
lw $t5, 12($s6)
loop: 
slt $t6, $t5, $t4
bne $t6, 1 END
lw $t6, $t5
lw $t5, $t4
lw $t4, $t6
addi $t5, $t5, -4
addi $t4, $t4, -4
j loop
END
```

I know this isn't correct but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: "Turning C program to MIPS assembly", isn't that the job of the *compiler*? ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry if the title is inaccurate, english is not my main language.

Comment: You have C code to start with -- that's good.  But you should run & test the C code to make sure it works.  It doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Your C doesn't look like a complete sorting algorithm.  At best an inner loop of insertionsort or something?  (I'm assuming it's C using byte offsets for arrays, not actual C checking elements 4 elements apart.)  Also it has no loop exit condition to stop you from going off the end.

Comment: Your assembly code has is not an accurate translation of the C code.  There's multiple loads before the loop, which the C code doesn't have.  So, it's not going to run the same as the C code.  Also, there's no such operation as `lw $t6, $t5`.  The MARS assembler, for example, won't take that.

Comment: Once you have working C code, then translate each C language statement exactly as it stands.  Don't try to improve while translating.  If you want to make improvements, do them in C first, run & test to make sure it works.  You loose the benefit  of having working C code if you change the basics of the algorithm  in the translation to assembly.

Comment: A tip: put a comment on each asm line and show the C operation you're trying to do. Some of my previous answers are similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52750900/5382650 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467899/5382650 https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262902/5382650 Here is a full `mips` bubble sort impl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015394/5382650

Comment: What is the type of `A`?